# Persistent video stream with PHP / JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, streaming

I'm looking for a way to create a movie stream that works much like a TV channel. Basically the movies play constantly, whether people are viewing the page or not. Users might come to the page and the current movie is halfway through. Once one movie is done, the next one plays, and so on.

I can't figure out how to make this work, though. Right now I have the player working where every time the page is loaded a random video is chosen and played, but this isn't what I want. Does anyone have any ideas on how I might get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a schedule of your video stream in a storage. This way you know which video is going to be played or be playing at any given time.

Now I know this is not the exact way a streaming service would work but it will get the job done for you. When a user loads a page your system computes which video should be playing at that time. Once the video is chosen, your system should compute the difference in the current time and the time when the video was supposed to start. Then you adjust the seek in your player i.e. you provide the start time of the video to the player as the time difference between the current time and the time when the video was supposed to start. This makes the video play from a position which is not necessarily its start.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use your exact solution, but it made me think of a similar way that seems to do what I need it to do. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you elaborate on the solution you used. Just out of curiosity...